# Backup home ecryptfs

Tags: linux, шифрование, резервное-копирование

Было настроено шифрование home используя ecryptfs-migrate-home, ключ имеется.

Как корректно настроить резервное копирование home на другой диск, чтобы он был также зашифрованным? В идеале, если бы к нему подходил тот же ключ?

Резервное копирование будет запускаться во время входа пользователя в систему т.е. на уже подключенном home разделе, который становится доступным после входа в систему под этим пользователем.

Либо может быть есть еще варианты?

Comment: Если диск не меньшего размера, то сможет просто `rsync` запускать.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать использовать `dd`. Например скопировать один раздел жёсткого диска на другой жёсткий диск, игнорируя ошибки ввода-вывода:

`dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sdb2 bs=4096 conv=noerror,sync`